# if a session expire how to redirect to working page after login

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, session

Hi am doing session handling, for example i am login with correct username and password on successful login i set session based on remember me checkbox then i will get dashboard after from dashboard  i will navigate to userDetails.jsp here if session gets expire it will redirect to login after again login how should i redirect to userDetails.jsp

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this using spring security

**Controller**

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String loginAuthentication(@ModelAttribute("accountForm") Account account, ModelMap modelMap,
                HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

            AccountModel accountModel = new AccountModel();

            if (accountModel.login(account.getUsername(), account.getPassword())) {
                if (request.getParameter("remember") != null) {
                    session.setAttribute("username", account.getUsername());
                    session.setMaxInactiveInterval(100);
                    return "redirect:dashboard";
                } else {
                    session.setAttribute("username", account.getUsername());
                    session.setMaxInactiveInterval(30);
                    return "redirect:dashboard";
                }
            } else {
                modelMap.put("errorMSg", "invalid login");
                return "login";
            }

        }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/userDetails", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String checkPage(ModelMap modelMap, HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {



        return "userDetails";
        }   

    @RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public String dashBoardPage(ModelMap modelMap, HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("*********" + session.getAttribute("username"));
        System.out.println(count);
        if (session.getAttribute("username") == null) {
            modelMap.put("accountForm", new Account());
            return "loginPage";
        }
        return "dashBoardPage";
    }
```

**userDetails.jsp**

```
 <c:if test="${empty sessionScope.username}">
  <c:redirect url= "/login"/>
</c:if>
```

**dashBoard.jsp**

```
  <c:if test="${empty sessionScope.username}">
      <c:redirect url= "/login"/>
    </c:if> 

<a href="userdetails">Userdetails</a>
```